# Date doesn't work in front matter defaults in Jekyll

Tags: yaml, jekyll

I want my posts to be the same date. So I put the following in my `_config.yml` file:

```
defaults:
  -
    scope:
      path: ""
      type: "post"
    values:
      layout: "post"
      date: "31.05.2014"
```

When I build the site, all posts get post layout, but instead of the date specified in front matter defaults, I get the date specified in the names of the posts initially. Although when I add the date manually to the front matter of each post, it works.

So any idea whether the date can be set in front matter defaults or not? If yes, how can I do it?

Comment: Can you please try English date formats like `2014-05-19 08:55:27`? __edit:__ Can't get it to work myself, sorry. :/

Comment: Also, why would you do that? What is your use case?

Comment: @kleinfreund I tried English date format, it didn't work for me also. I use posts as articles in a knowledge base. By date I would like to indicate that the information is up-to-date on a certain date. So next time I review the knowledge base I would like to have one place where I can change the date for all posts, instead of doing it manually in each post.

Comment: What if you don't use Front Matter and only use the same date in the file names? Of course you would still need to adjust these manually.

Comment: @kleinfreund that's the point, changing the date manually either way will take a lot of time.

Answer (score 1):

Based on what you want, I think [Jekyll's data feature](http://jekyllrb.com/docs/datafiles) may be of better use here. You could specify a `last_updated_at` field with a date in a data file and then use that throughout your site. You could then allow the post filename to indicate when the knowledge base article was created, or bump the post date (if it's not part of the permalink) to indicate when each article was last updated.